# Automator - Moving files to a newly created folder

Tags: macos, automator, finder

I am trying to set up a folder action to do the following... If a file is added to "SSD 1" External then a new dated folder would automatically be created inside folder "2020", and the file(s) would be moved to this new dated subfolder created.

Here are the steps I've been at-

1) Folder action receives files and folders added to "SSD 1"

2) Filter finder items - Find files where ALL of the following is true: Kind is ANY

3) New Folder - Name is "SUNDAY" Where: "2020"

Another question I have is- I can't seem to figure out what script to use to make the date format be "YYYY.MM.DD" and also how to make automator trash the files on "SSD 1" after the files have been successfully moved over then Wipe Mac Trash Can at the end

Lastly, It's going to be used with New Data on the SSD... So every time I plug in "SSD 1" the automator will start the process of the moving the files from the SSD to the said Folder then deleting all files off of the SSD

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: Is the format going to be used for the current date, and where are you planning to use it?

Comment: It's going to be used with New Data... So every time I plug in SSD 1 the automator will start the process of the moving the files from the SSD to the said Folder then deleting all files off of the SSD